# Flask authentication with Flask-Security

Tags: python, authentication, flask

Trying to enable login in flask with flask-security. The following code works fine (I import in `__init__.py`)

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from coursly import app
from coursly.models import *
from flask.ext.security import Security, LoginForm, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, user.User, user.Role)
Security(app, user_datastore)

user = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@user.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for("user.login"))

@user.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('user/login.html', content='Login Page', action=url_for('auth.authenticate'), form=LoginForm())
```

If, however, I change `user = Blueprint('user', __name__)` to `user = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/blah')` it fails with a `werkzeug.routing.BuildError BuildError: ('auth.authenticate', {}, None)`. url_for is the problem, however, I don't understand why. HALP!

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out. Turns out Flask-security already has `/login` `/logout` built in and my login function was largely ignored. It wasn't used during normal app execution. Except `url_for` was still processed hence the BuildError.

I was trying to use an outdated example from https://github.com/dracule/FlaskBootstrapSecurity and it was a fail. Flask-Security was updated 3 mo ago. The action param should be updated to `action=url_for('security.login')` and it will work.

TL;DR adding a `url_prefix` will not use Flask-Security's built in `/login` `/logout` and a lot of vars were renamed

Comment: You should accept your answer, even if it's your own. That way it's properly shown as "answered" here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but just in case someone has this problem as I had, [here's the related documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html)